# OpenAM adding groups and users in datastore

Tags: authentication, openam

I'm able to add users via datastore (MySql) however not able to add groups. I'm having both users and groups tables as prescribed in datastore page. Any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group related operations are not implemented in the OOTB JDBC data store implementation. If you need those, then you'll need to write a custom data store implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the DAO implementation provided by OpenAM JdbcSimpleUserDao returns empty collection.